# How to improve controller code in large CRUD applications?

Tags: doctrine-orm, coding-style, doctrine, symfony

Most of the time I work on web applications which use CRUD features. It's almost the same everytime I create a new website.

For example I have this code, how could I improve it?

**Is this really bad practice or is it normal to have such code in a CRUD application?**

I use Symfony 3.0 with Doctrine 2.5.

```php
/**
 * @Route("/", name="contacts")
 */
public function listAction(Request $request)
{
    /* @var $em EntityManager */
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $searchTerm = $request->get('q');
    $currentGroupId = $request->get('g');

    $qb = $em->createQueryBuilder()
        ->select('c')
        ->from('AppBundle:Contact', 'c')
        ->leftJoin('c.phones', 'p');

    // Get current group from session if not passed by request
    if (empty($currentGroupId)) {
        $request->getSession()->get('contact_current_group_id');
    }

    // Get search term from session if not passed by request
    if (empty($searchTerm)) {
        $request->getSession()->get('contact_search_term');
    }

    // Search if search term is not empty
    if (!empty($searchTerm)) {
        $orX = $qb->expr()->orX();
        $orX->add($qb->expr()->like('c.name', ':searchTerm'));
        $orX->add($qb->expr()->like('p.number', ':searchTerm'));
        $qb->andWhere($orX);
        $qb->setParameter('searchTerm', '%'.$searchTerm.'%');
    }

    // Get and check current group
    $currentGroup = null;
    if ($currentGroupId) {
        $currentGroup = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:ContactGroup')
            ->findOneBy(['enabled' => true, 'id' => $currentGroupId]);

        if ($currentGroup) {
            $qb->andWhere(':groupId MEMBER OF c.groups');
            $qb->setParameter('groupId', $currentGroupId);
        }
    }

    // Get contacts / Pagination
    $paginator = $this->get('knp_paginator');
    $contacts = $paginator->paginate($qb->getQuery(),
        $request->query->getInt('page', 1), 25);

    // Get all groups
    $groups = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:ContactGroup')
        ->findBy(['enabled' => true]);

    return $this->render('contact/list.html.twig', [
        'currentGroup' => $currentGroup,
        'searchTerm' => $searchTerm,
        'contacts' => $contacts,
        'groups' => $groups,
    ]);
}
```

### Update 1

Edit: I have done some changes on the code. What could be done to improve the code yet? What are your Best Practices?

```php
/**
 * @Route("/", name="contacts")
 */
public function listAction(Request $request)
{
    /* @var $em EntityManager */
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    /* @var $repo ContactRepository */
    $repoContact = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Contact');
    /* @var $repo ContactGroupRepository */
    $repoGroup = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:ContactGroup');

    // Request parameters
    $searchTerm = $request->get('q', $request->getSession()->get('contact_search_term'));;
    $currentGroupId = $request->get('g', $request->getSession()->get('contact_current_group_id'));

    // Queries
    $allGroups = $repoGroup->findByEnabled();
    $currentGroup = $repoGroup->findOneByEnabledAndId($currentGroupId);
    $contactsQuery = $repoContact->createListQuery($searchTerm, $currentGroup);

    // Pagination
    $paginator = $this->get('knp_paginator');
    $contacts = $paginator->paginate($contactsQuery, $request->query->getInt('page', 1), 25);

    return $this->render('contact/list.html.twig', [
        'currentGroup' => $currentGroup,
        'searchTerm' => $searchTerm,
        'contacts' => $contacts,
        'groups' => $allGroups,
    ]);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what is known as an opinion based question and will probably end up being closed as such.  But I have never been overly shy about offering my opinion.

Your code is actually quite common.  Symfony is a Request/Response based framework in which the controller is responsible for generating a response based on a request.  Which is exactly what your code does.  It's quite easy to read and quite clear as to what it does.  Quite frankly, if another developer cannot look at your code and figure out what is going on then that developer really should not be messing with the project anyways.

One downside of your approach is that if you do end up making significant changes to the way the Contact entity is modeled then you might have quite a bit of code to search through and update,  Easy to overlook something.  Your approach might also result in extra code duplication.  For example, if there are other controller actions that need enabled contact groups then you will end up duplicating the same query.  Which again might be okay if you are comfortable with the code and the project is reasonably stable.

You might also have problems if you want to maybe write some commands.  You will end up having to copy/paste code from the controller and once again end up with duplicate code.  Likewise if you ever decided to do something like adding a REST api.

So if you did want to refine things a bit then (as @tooni has suggested), moving functionality into repositories would be a good starting point.  Using repositories will let you isolate query specific functionality and perhaps avoid repeating code.

In your case you could define the contact repository as a service resulting in:

```
$contactRepo = $this->get('contact_repository');
$contactQuery = $contactRepo->createQuery($currentGroup,$searchTerm);
$contactGroups = $contactRepo->getEnabledContactGroups();
```

With this approach your controller code becomes simpler.  All the query building stuff get's moved into the repository.  You can share some functionality.  A more subtle advantage is that your controller no longer needs to know about 'AppBundle:Contact'.  It just knows that it is getting a contact query of some sort.  In fact your controller is no longer directly dependent on Doctrine at all.

And if you really want to get into it then define your controller as a service and inject the repository as well as the paginator service.  Now your controller is independent of the dependency injection container as well.

In conclusion, if your code works for you and maintaining it is not a big problem then stick with it.  If you want to try a bit more sophisticated approach then break out the repository and see what happens.

Comment: Thanks! I've changed my code and posted the new code ("Update 1"). Would be awesome if you have some more improvements. This will help me and maybe a lot of other people to understand the current best practices.

Comment: This sort of question/discussion is just not a good fit for stackoverflow.

Comment: +1 This is a proper answer but also note that it would be best to read the Symfony book and best practices rather than posting on SO.

Answer (score 2):

It really is bad practice. You should never build your query inside the Controller. Move the stuff into a Repository (in your case a `ContactRepository`) and pass the vars from the controller to a function called something like "createSearchQuery". In there you can build the query and return it to the controller. From there you can pass it over to the `paginator`.

In general - Try to move as much logic as possible out of the controller. In as small functions as possible. This helps other Developers to understand your code and makes the code better for testing.

Comment: Thanks! I've changed my code and posted the new code ("Update 1"). Would be awesome if you have some more improvements. This will help me and maybe a lot of other people to understand the current best practices.